# Docker-compose specify config file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and now I want to use `docker-compose`. I would like to provide the `docker-compose.yml` script the config file with host/port, maybe credentials and other cassandra configuration.

[***DockerHub link.***](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/cassandra/)

How to specify it in the compose script:

```
cassandra:
  image: bitnami/cassandra:latest
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using Docker compose environment variables(https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substituting-environment-variables-in-compose-files). You can also specify a separate environment file with environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, including a file outside of the scope of the image build, such as a config file, has been a [major point of discussion](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1664) (and perhaps some tension) between the community and the folks at Docker. A lot of the developers in that linked issue recommended adding config files in a folder as a volume (unfortunately, you cannot add an individual file).

It would look something like:

```
volumes:
  - ./config_folder:./config_folder
```

Where `config_folder` would be at the root of your project, at the same level as the Dockerfile.

Comment: The above would mount the `config_folder` allowing the container to access it -- but how does one tell Docker Compose, 'Hey, the config file you need is in this folder'?

Comment: I'm asking because I was given a compose file which requires version `3.3`, but I am working on an environment that only has `3.1` installed. Not able to upgrade the environment. It seems the `configs` property is the one throwing the error and I'm trying to find a workaround to downgrade it easily and safely to `3.1`.

Answer (score -1):

If Docker compose environment cannot solved your problem, you should create a new image from the original image with COPY to override the file.

Dockerfile:

```
From orginal_image:xxx
COPY local_conffile in_image_dir/conf_dir/
```